# Browser messing up sidebars when reducing size

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/

Hi there,

please can someone help. Ive done this on a "float" style with % margins etc.... but when for example i resize the browser the sidebars go all messy...

This is my CSS markup

```
#MainContent {
width: 53%;
float: left;
margin-left: 110px;
margin-top: -247px;
padding-top: 0px;
background-color: #ffffff;
font-family: verdana;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 8pt;
color: #000000;
}
#rightsidebar {
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 26%;
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: -247px;
}
 #FooterWrapper {
width: 81.2%;
clear:both;
height: 20px;
background-color: #145618;
color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 110px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
 #chunkyfooter {
 clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
width: 81.2%;
padding-top: 8px;
margin-left: 110px;
text-align: center;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 10px;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

thanks :)

Kirsty

Comment: Do you have an example? Either your site or an example at www.jsfiddle.net would be great.

Comment: On what browser are you testing ?

Comment: Hey guys, this is on Chrome. The above address is my test site.

Comment: try giving your #rightsidebar a min-width attribute in pixels, that way it will stop shrinking when it reaches a certain width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to mix two units in the same element, maybe this is the cause of your problems.
Some people like to mix the two kinds of units, pixel and percentage, but I always try to always use pixels.

My suggestion, choose the one you are most comfortable with and stick with it and as long as you don't mix different units in the same element you should be fine.